# Gulp 4 - Error: write after end

Tags: node.js, typescript, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-4

I'm getting an error when I watch for changes in `index.html` (full path in `CONFIG.APP.INDEX`). All my tasks are in separate files. this is **tasks/watch.ts**, for example:

```
import * as CONFIG from '../config';

export default done => {
  // other watches
  gulp.watch(CONFIG.APP.INDEX, gulp.series('inject'));
};
```

on first change task is executed normally, but on second change I'm getting this error:

```
c:\~\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:203
  var er = new Error('write after end');
           ^
Error: write after end
    at writeAfterEnd (c:\~\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:203:12)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (c:\~\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:239:20)
    at DestroyableTransform.ondata (c:\~\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:531:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at readableAddChunk (c:\~\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:198:18)
    at DestroyableTransform.Readable.push (c:\~\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:157:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform.push (c:\~\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:123:32)
    at afterTransform (c:\~\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:79:51)
    at TransformState.afterTransform (c:\~\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:58:12)
    at c:\~\node_modules\vinyl-fs\lib\src\getContents\bufferFile.js:18:5
    at c:\~\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:78:16
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:404:3)
```

**tasks/inject.ts** task:

```
declare var require;
const gulp = require('gulp');
const plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
import * as CONFIG from '../config';

export default done => {
  return gulp
    .src(CONFIG.APP.INDEX)

    .pipe(require('../util/inject/fixes').default) // <--- PROBLEM IS HERE
    // other stuff...
    .pipe(gulp.dest(CONFIG.DST.BUILD))
    .on('error', plugins.util.log);
};
```

**util/inject/fixes.ts** task

```
declare var require;
const plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

// errors even with this...
export default plugins.util.noop();
```

Tasks are loaded from `gulpfile.ts/index.ts` like this:

```
fs.readdirSync('./gulpfile.ts/tasks').map(file => {
  let name = file.replace(/\.ts$/, '');
  let task = require(path.join(path.resolve('.'), 'gulpfile.ts', 'tasks', file));
  gulp.task(name, task.default);
});
```

I've managed to identify where the error comes from, but no idea what's causing it, or how to fix it. Problem only occurs when watching `index.html` ***after first change and task execution***. Running task manually works normally (`gulp inject`), and all other watches and tasks work normally.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that your implementation of `fixes.ts` is reusing the same `noop()` result instead of recreating the result each time the task is run.

Try converting the `fixes.ts` to return a **factory function** that will return a new `noop` instance each time the task is invoked.

**util/inject/fixes.ts**:

```
declare var require;
const plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

// Return a function that will return a new `noop` instance each time:
export default () => {
    return plugins.util.noop();
};
```

---

For context, I just had a similar problem in my project where I was accidentally reusing a gulp stream and getting the "write after end" error.

I suspect your code is doing the same sort of thing with the `noop()` result because that one value will be cached as the value of that module.

**Incorrect** version of my gulpfile.js - the result of my `gulp.dest()` calls was being reused each time.

```
let gulp = require('gulp');
let merge = require('merge-stream');

let _path = require('path');

let files = {
    'html': {
        src: _path.join('public', 'index.html'),
        dest: gulp.dest('public')  // <-- WRONG use of `gulp.dest()`, causes result to be reused and gives "write after end" error
    },
    'files': 'html': {
        src: _path.join('files', '*'),
        dest: gulp.dest('files')  // <-- WRONG use of`gulp.dest()`
    },
};

gulp.task('copy', function(){
    let html = gulp.src(files.html.src)
        .pipe(files.html.dest);   // <-- `gulp.dest()` should be here

    let files = gulp.src(files.files.src)
        .pipe(files.files.dest);  // <-- `gulp.dest()` should be here

    return merge(html, files);
});


gulp.task('copy-watch', function(){
    let srcList = Object.keys(files).map(i => files[i].src);
    gulp.watch(srcList, ['copy']);
});
```

**Fixed** version of my gulpfile.js - `gulp.dest()` is being called each time the task is run:

```
let files = {
    'html': {
        src: _path.join('public', 'index.html'),
        dest: 'public'  // <-- removed `gulp.dest()` call from here
    },
    'files': 'html': {
        src: _path.join('files', '*'),
        dest: 'files'  // <-- removed `gulp.dest()` call from here
    },
};

gulp.task('copy', function(){
    let html = gulp.src(files.html.src)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(files.html.dest));  // <-- CORRECT use of`gulp.dest()`

    let files = gulp.src(files.files.src)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(files.files.dest)); // <-- CORRECT use of `gulp.dest()`

    return merge(html, files);
});
```